# Which DSE keyspaces are necessary for a full backup restore?

Tags: datastax-enterprise

When I list keyspaces on my DSE cluster I get

```
myuser@cqlsh> DESC KEYSPACES;

dse_security  system       "OpsCenter"      system_traces  cfs
system_auth   cfs_archive  "HiveMetaStore"  XXXXXXXX       dse_system
```

where `XXXXXXXX` is our internal keyspace and the rest are essentially systems keyspaces. **Which of the above can easily be recreated without a backup?** AFAIK, neither [What are best practices for backing up a cassandra cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31439039/260805) nor [Backing up and restoring data in Datastax documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_backup_restore_c.html) answers this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Opscenter will create the "OpsCenter" keyspace. Installing DSE will re-create the other system keyspaces. I think the only ks you need to worry about is your own user-defined keyspace. Don't forget to backup your schema, you will need that in order to do the restore.